# Node.js Global Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is list of debugger queries, and responses, executed in a node.js at the global scope level:

```js
this.toString()
    "[object Object]"
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).toString()
    "[object Object]"
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
    null
this.constructor
    function Object() { [native code] }
Object.prototype.toString()
    "[object Object]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(this)
    "[object Object]"

Function.prototype.toString()
    "function () {}"
Function.prototype.toString.call(this)
    TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic
```

The first set of responses suggests that the global scope is represented by an object that extends Object.prototype, as might be expected. So I'd expect that calling Function.prototype's *.toString()* on *this* would fail, as indeed it does (see the last query). I was expecting the query preceding that to pass an implicit *this* and so fail likewise, but it returns *function () {}*.

Why the difference, and what function is being referenced in the response?

Comment: The 2nd to last is equivalent to `Function.prototype.toString.call(Function.prototype)`. The value of `this` from the global scope isn't used by it.

Answer (score 0):

In a function call, `this` is bound to either the object that "the function was called on" or the global object, for example:

```
const obj = {
  foo() {
    console.log(this);
  },
};

obj.foo(); // this is bound to obj
const obj2 = {};
obj2.bar = obj.foo;
obj2.bar(); // this is bound to obj2
const g = obj.foo;
g(); // this is bound to the global object
```

Therefore, `Function.prototype.toString()` is exactly the same as `Function.prototype.toString.call(Function.prototype)`. That's the matter of implementation of this function that it throws if called on anything other than a Function.